# Can a plain Ruby object instance return a primitive?

Tags: ruby, return-value

How can I define a class whose instance without a method call returns a string representation of itself, without `instance.to_s` or similar being called?

Is there a method that defines the native return for an instance when invoked without a method, which can strip all the object handling and just return a primitive?

The same way as `String` behaves:

```
>> str=String.new('abc')
>> s
"abc"
```

`str` doesn't return

```
#<String abc>
```

Or does it, and is it, just the console extracting the value?

How can I make `Class('abc')` do the same thing as `Class.new('abc')` does for `String`? Sub-classing `String` is an option, but I'd like to know alternatives.

Comment: Aren't you confusing "value of an expression" and "what IRB prints for this expression"? The latter is merely a side-effect. Doesn't have anything to do with actual value.

Comment: What is `s` in your examples?

Comment: It is confusing to write `Class` as representing some arbitrary class. `Class` already means something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bonus points for explaining how to make Class('abc') do the same thing as Class.new('abc') as it does for String.

Easy. Just define a class **and** a method with the same name.

```
class Hello
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

def Hello(name)
  Hello.new(name)
end

Hello('world') # => #<Hello:0x007fb376181d08 @name="world">
Hello.new('another world') # => #<Hello:0x007fb3761814e8 @name="another world">
```

Not very ambiguous, as far as ruby is concerned. `Hello('world')` is clearly a method call, so it's treated as such.

Plain `Hello` could mean both. In which case it is treated as the constant (otherwise it'd be quite difficult to refer to the constant).

---

*This was shown for education purposes only. Don't actually do this in production code. Without a very good reason, at least.*

Comment: The `def Hello` method would probably go in `Kernel` with all the other things that "we want to pretend are global functions even though we don't really have such things".

Comment: A production ready example written in Ruby is stdlib's `Kernel::URI` which is defined in [`uri/common.rb`, line 733](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_1/lib/uri/common.rb#L728-L744).

Answer (score 2):

If you enter following in irb then you should see the expected result:

```
class Foo
  def inspect
    "foo"
  end
end

Foo.new #> "foo"
```

But that is just how it is displayed. So I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Creating a String

```
s = String.new('abc')
```

is actually constructing two strings: one for the literal 'abc' and then one for the call to `new`, so it is pointless unless you want to create a duplicate.

Perhaps if you tell a bit more about what you want to achieve then you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't have "primitives", everything is an object, even Class, `nil`, the number `1` and very string.

As such, the only way it knows what to print with tools like `irb` is the `inspect` method defined for each. In the case of `String` there's a default `inspect` that simply returns the string itself encoded as it would be double-quoted in your source code.

As an example:

```
class Showoff
  def inspect
    "Look at me!"
  end
end
```

Trying this in `irb`:

```
Showoff.new
# => Look at me!
```

Note that `String.new` is almost always pointless as `String.new(x)` doesn't really do anything that `x` doesn't do. If you want a forced copy: `x.dup` will give you one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to do, but you can also make an inheritance from the `String` class and then add your custom behavior:

```
class SomethingSpecial < String
  def say_hello
    p 'Hello'
  end
end

special = SomethingSpecial.new('something')

p special # => "something"
p special.class # => SomethingSpecial
special.say_hello # => "Hello"
```

Also, it's a rare case when capitalized methods are used in Ruby. The common way is to use `snake_case_method_naming`.

Comment: Inheriting from base classes, like String or Array, is especially bad idea. What would `special.upcase` return?

Comment: If I need to add custom behavior to core objects, I usually `extend` instances with a module containing the methods, i.e. on a per-instance basis.